# Angular HttpClient - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, http, cors, httpclient

Im trying to setup a basic HttpRequest to get an image of an Axis camera.

Im trying the following:

```
return this.httpClient.get<Blob>('http://192.168.1.235/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi', {
  headers: {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'blob',
  }
});
```

Which gives me the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://192.168.1.235/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I can call this url using my browser and postman without any settings or authentification needed so i don't think its a camera setting.

Anybody can help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: If its just for local use and you want to by pass securiry you could disable it in a chrome instance. with command `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` on windows. Not recommended though. Also don't use the browser instance for anything else

Answer (score 0):

`http://192.168.1.235` must allow external sites to access its resources. It is done by responding to `OPTIONS` request with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. CORS rules are enforced by the browser and there is not much you can do with it in the browser itself (therfore your Angular app). Disabling security is fine for develop purposes, but it is rather inpossible to require it for every user of your application:) One hack is to use proxy to serve required resource so you can bypass CORS rules.

Read more about [CORS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: So if i understand this correct, i will not run into this error when im not in local anymore? So that means the request is coming from f.e. 192.168.1.200:4200, then there will be no problem?

Comment: Not "not in local" but rather "anywere else then 192.168.1.235" If you would deploy your app on `192.168.1.235` then the problem would be gone - no CORS rules applies as it is the same origin. Hack -> use proxy to serve remote resources as "your own"

Comment: So, but 192.168.1.235, which is the camera in this case, allows external requests. I can access the url in any browser and i can call it with postman. Only my angular application is having issues.

Comment: If you run it on your browser, it's the same origin. So there is no CORS error in this case. It works on Postman because it doesn't care about SOP. Postman is a dev tool not a browser.

Comment: CORS are enforced by BROWSER, it will work in postman. Moreover it will work if you paste your URL to the browser! But here, you are using XHR to fetch resources witch is a different story. Read CORS details that I have provided to get more insight. Long story short - it works as intended.

Comment: @FlorianTaut it might also work if you would remove custom headers. Read more about WHEN CORS rules are applied here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests